# Shortest path algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I understand what is being done up to where the first two rows have been filled, but after that I'm completely lost. I understand we have to now look for adjacent vertices to E which are C,F and A and I understand that the the edge EC has weight  3, weight of the edge EF is 5 and EA is 2. So now temp(u) for E is temp(E) which is 2 and so temp(u)/temp(E)+weight of edge EC is 5,  temp(u)/temp(E)+weight of edge EF is 7, but after this I'm lost.
Also what is temp(v) so e.g for vertex F, temp(v)/temp(F) is the minimum distance from the starting point A? If so then is that 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things here, an algorithm and a grid. The algorithm is written
so that it does not assume a grid representation.
The grid is evidently meant as an aid in recording the steps of the algorithm 
but the instructions for filling in the grid must have come from somewhere else
(either verbal instructions or something or something that is not shown here),
but seeing how the grid was filled in in this example it seems you
were to fill in one line of the grid for each iteration of the
"repeat while done(finish)=no" loop.

Line 2 of the grid (the first line with $12$ in column B)
represents the "state" of the algorithm after
the first iteration of the loop but before the second iteration.
At that time, as you correctly observed, 
$\mbox{temp}(E)+\mbox{weight}(EC) = 5$ and 
$\mbox{temp}(E)+\mbox{weight}(EF) = 7$.
Also, at the beginning of the loop, 
$\mbox{temp}(C)=77$ and $\mbox{temp}(F)=3$
(reading these values off line 2).

So, looking at $C$,
$\mbox{temp}(E)+\mbox{weight}(EC) = 5 < 77 = \mbox{temp}(C),$
therefore we follow the "if smaller than temp(v)" instructions:
we set $\mbox{temp}(C)$ to $5$ and we set $\mbox{last}(C)$ to $E$.
What this means for the grid is we put $5$ on line 3 in column C
and $E$ at the bottom of column C.

But looking at $F$,
$\mbox{temp}(E)+\mbox{weight}(EF) = 7 > 3 = \mbox{temp}(F),$
so we do *not* follow the "if smaller than temp(v)" instructions.
Instead, in column F and in the columns for
every other "not done" vertex that was not touched yet in this iteration,
we simply copy the number from line 2 to line 3.
We see that $\mbox{temp}(F)$ is the smallest "temp" value on line 3, so
we set $\mbox{done}(F)$ to "yes" and set $u$ to $F$;
on the grid this means we circle the number one line 3 of column F
and we write $F$ at the end of line 3.

At first glance this looks like one of those things where you should just
be more careful to follow the next step every time, but in my opinion
the algorithm is not written up clearly
(phrases like "use it to update temp(v)" are not the most helpful!).

Comment: @ David K : I know it says here, to avoid comments like thanks but I don't care, I had been trying to decode the nonsensical language in which my lecturer had written this algorithm for hours. Thank you soooooo much!